R sankey networkD3 - set colour of target nodes
I want to create a sankey diagram setting different custom colours for source AND target nodes.
The source nodes (and the links) get coloured as intended. However, the targets do not take the desired colours. Below is the code I'm using:
# Install packages
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(dplyr, readxl, networkD3)

# Load libraries
library(readxl)
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

# Generate data
data <- data.frame(
  Recommendation = c("Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", 
             "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", 
             "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", 
             "Include social justice", "Include social justice", "Include social justice", "Include social justice", 
             "Many future scenarios", 
             "Consider NbS as an option", "Consider NbS as an option", "Consider NbS as an option", 
             "Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities", "Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities", "Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities", "Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities", 
             "Move beyond monetary valuation", "Move beyond monetary valuation", "Move beyond monetary valuation", 
             "Multi-scalar valuation", "Multi-scalar valuation", "Multi-scalar valuation", 
             "Draw on pilots/past examples", "Draw on pilots/past examples", 
             "Improve awareness of NbS co-benefits", 
             "Multiple financing approaches", 
             "Early and continued monitoring/maintenance", "Early and continued monitoring/maintenance", 
             "Behavior/experience mapping", "Behavior/experience mapping", "Behavior/experience mapping"
             ),
  Barrier = c("Compartimentalisation", "Myopic decision-making", "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Disregard trade-offs", "Lack of public support", "Disregard justice", "Secure funding", "No long-term monitoring", "Economic growth paradigm", 
             "Uncertainty", "Path dependence", "Compartimentalisation", "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Limitations in evaluation methods", "Disregard trade-offs", "Lack of public support", "Disregard justice", "Secure funding", "No long-term monitoring", "Lack of supporting regulation", "Economic growth paradigm", 
             "Compartimentalisation", "Path dependence", "Myopic decision-making", "Lack of supporting regulation", 
             "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Disregard trade-offs", "Disregard justice", "Economic growth paradigm", 
             "Uncertainty", 
             "Compartimentalisation", "Path dependence", "Lack of supporting regulation", 
             "Compartimentalisation", "Path dependence", "Myopic decision-making", "Lack of supporting regulation", 
             "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Limitations in evaluation methods", "Disregard trade-offs", 
             "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Limitations in evaluation methods", "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", 
             "Uncertainty", "Secure funding", 
             "Lack of public support", 
             "Secure funding", 
             "Lack of supporting regulation", "No long-term monitoring", 
             "Context dependence", "Disregard trade-offs", "Lack of public support"),
  Value = 1
)

# Create links data
links <- 
  data %>% 
  rename(source = Recommendation, target = Barrier, value = Value)

# Create nodes data
ordered_barriers <- c('Uncertainty',
                      'Path dependence',
                      'Compartimentalisation',
                      'Myopic decision-making',
                      'Context dependence',
                      'Undervaluation of multifunctionality',
                      'Limitations in evaluation methods',
                      'Disregard trade-offs',
                      'Lack of public support',
                      'Disregard justice',
                      'Secure funding',
                      'No long-term monitoring',
                      'Lack of supporting regulation',
                      'Economic growth paradigm')
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(data$Recommendation, ordered_barriers)))

links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

nodes$group <- gsub(" ", "-", nodes$name)

color_scale <-
  "d3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(['Participatory decision-making process', 'Involve wide range of experts', 'Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS', 'Include social justice',
         'Many future scenarios', 'Consider NbS as an option', 'Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities',
         'Move beyond monetary valuation', 'Multi-scalar valuation', 'Draw on pilots/past examples',
         'Improve awareness of NbS co-benefits', 'Multiple financing approaches',
         'Early and continued monitoring/maintenance', 'Behavior/experience mapping',
         'Uncertainty', 'Path-dependence', 'Compartimentalisation', 'Myopic decision-making', 'Context dependence',
         'Undervaluation of multifunctionality', 'Limitations in evaluation methods', 'Disregard trade-offs',
         'Lack of public support', 'Disregard justice', 'Secure funding',
         'No long-term monitoring', 'Lack of supporting regulation', 'Economic growth paradigm'])
     .range(['#3182BDFF', '#6BAED6FF', '#9ECAE1FF', '#C6DBEFFF',
         '#74C476FF', '#A1D99BFF', '#C7E9C0FF',
         '#FD8D3CFF', '#FDAE6BFF', '#FDD0A2FF',
         '#BD9E39FF', '#E7BA52FF',
         '#D6616BFF', '#E7969CFF',
         '#31A354FF', '#31A354FF', '#31A354FF', '#31A354FF', '#31A354FF',
         '#E6550DFF', '#E6550DFF', '#E6550DFF',
         '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF',
         '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF',
         ]);
  "

# Create the Sankey diagram
sn <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links, 
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source_id",
  Target = "target_id",
  Value = "value",
  NodeID = "name",
  LinkGroup = "source",
  fontSize = 10,
  NodeGroup = "name",
  colourScale = color_scale,
  iterations = 0
)

# Move labels outside of diagram
sn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  sn,
  paste0('
        function(el,x){
        d3.select(el)
        .selectAll(".node text")
        .filter(function(d) { return (["',paste0(links$source,collapse = '","'),'"].indexOf(d.name) > -1);})
        .attr("x", x.options.nodeWidth - 20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");
        d3.select(el)
        .selectAll(".node text")
        .filter(function(d) { return (["',paste0(links$target,collapse = '","'),'"].indexOf(d.name) > -1);})
        .attr("x", x.options.nodeWidth + 5)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start");
        }
        ')
)

# Display the diagram
sn

I would like the targets to be coloured as declared in the code, but, as you can see from the picture, the result is not the desired one: Sankey.
It seems that the colours for the targets are not assigned correctly. For instance, if I change the colour of the first target (Uncertainty), the code changes the colour of the second target as well (Path dependence).
Here is the modified code:
color_scale <-
  "d3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(['Participatory decision-making process', 'Involve wide range of experts', 'Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS', 'Include social justice',
         'Many future scenarios', 'Consider NbS as an option', 'Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities',
         'Move beyond monetary valuation', 'Multi-scalar valuation', 'Draw on pilots/past examples',
         'Improve awareness of NbS co-benefits', 'Multiple financing approaches',
         'Early and continued monitoring/maintenance', 'Behavior/experience mapping',
         'Uncertainty', 'Path-dependence', 'Compartimentalisation', 'Myopic decision-making', 'Context dependence',
         'Undervaluation of multifunctionality', 'Limitations in evaluation methods', 'Disregard trade-offs',
         'Lack of public support', 'Disregard justice', 'Secure funding',
         'No long-term monitoring', 'Lack of supporting regulation', 'Economic growth paradigm'])
     .range(['#3182BDFF', '#6BAED6FF', '#9ECAE1FF', '#C6DBEFFF',
         '#74C476FF', '#A1D99BFF', '#C7E9C0FF',
         '#FD8D3CFF', '#FDAE6BFF', '#FDD0A2FF',
         '#BD9E39FF', '#E7BA52FF',
         '#D6616BFF', '#E7969CFF',
         '#1F77B4FF', '#31A354FF', '#31A354FF', '#31A354FF', '#31A354FF',
         '#E6550DFF', '#E6550DFF', '#E6550DFF',
         '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF',
         '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF', '#843C39FF',
         ]);
  "

And here the resulting diagram: Sankey (change colour of first target).
Similarly, changing other target colours leads to strange results (like multiple targets' colours are modified, targets in a different position from the one that was modified change colors).
I don't really understand why this is happening. I suspect there might some conflicts with how the nodes are defined and how the colours are assigned, but so far I haven't been able to identify where the issue is exactly.
Would someone be able to spot what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

I think you may have intended to use NodeGroup = "group" instead of NodeGroup = "name" in sankeyNetwork(), but even with that the names you list in the domain() of the JavaScript do not exactly match the names in nodes$name nor in nodes$group.

Thanks for your reply. If I switch to NodeGroup = "group" the source node colours are not assigned correctly. NodeGroup = "name" ensures that they are.  But like I said, there is probably some mismatch and I cannot identify  where/how to fix it. Would you have any idea? Or how should the code be changed to have the source (left-hand side) nodes and links coloured as they are now, and the target (right-hand side) nodes with different customary colours? Thanks!

I don’t have the time or interest in doing that work, but for instance you reference “Path-dependence” in the JavaScript domain which is not in nodes$name

After some fiddling around, I've managed to fix the issue. As I suspected, and as highlighted by @CJ Yetman, there where inconsistencies in how the names of the categories where defined in domain() and in nodes$name / nodes$group. Making the entries in domain() fully consistent with nodes$group and using NodeGroup = "group" in sankeyNetwork() did the trick.
Below is the working code to produce the attached graph: Correct sankey. I've made some modifications to the colours and the margins wrt the code posted in my question, but nothing significant.
# Install packages
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(dplyr, readxl, networkD3)

# Load libraries
library(readxl)
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

# Generate data
data <- data.frame(
  Recommendation = c("Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", "Participatory decision-making process", 
             "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", "Involve wide range of experts", 
             "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", "Legal/regulatory framework to assist NbS", 
             "Include social justice", "Include social justice", "Include social justice", "Include social justice", 
             "Many future scenarios", 
             "Consider NbS as an option", "Consider NbS as an option", "Consider NbS as an option", 
             "Disincentivise myopia", "Disincentivise myopia", "Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities", "Disincentivise myopia and internalise ES externalities", 
             "Move beyond monetary valuation", "Move beyond monetary valuation", "Move beyond monetary valuation", 
             "Multi-scalar valuation", "Multi-scalar valuation", "Multi-scalar valuation", 
             "Draw on pilots/past examples", "Draw on pilots/past examples", 
             "Improve awareness of NbS co-benefits", 
             "Multiple financing approaches", 
             "Early and continued monitoring", "Early and continued monitoring", 
             "Behavior/experience mapping", "Behavior/experience mapping", "Behavior/experience mapping"
             ),
  Barrier = c("Compartimentalisation", "Myopic decision-making", "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Disregard trade-offs", "Lack of public support", "Disregard justice", "Secure funding", "No long-term monitoring", "Economic growth paradigm", 
             "Uncertainty", "Path dependence", "Compartimentalisation", "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Limitations in evaluation methods", "Disregard trade-offs", "Lack of public support", "Disregard justice", "Secure funding", "No long-term monitoring", "Lack of supporting regulation", "Economic growth paradigm", 
             "Compartimentalisation", "Path dependence", "Myopic decision-making", "Lack of supporting regulation", 
             "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Disregard trade-offs", "Disregard justice", "Economic growth paradigm", 
             "Uncertainty", 
             "Compartimentalisation", "Path dependence", "Lack of supporting regulation", 
             "Compartimentalisation", "Path dependence", "Myopic decision-making", "Lack of supporting regulation", 
             "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Limitations in evaluation methods", "Disregard trade-offs", 
             "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", "Limitations in evaluation methods", "Undervaluation of multifunctionality", 
             "Uncertainty", "Secure funding", 
             "Lack of public support", 
             "Secure funding", 
             "Lack of supporting regulation", "No long-term monitoring", 
             "Context dependence", "Disregard trade-offs", "Lack of public support"),
  Value = 1
)

# Create links data
links <- 
  data %>% 
  rename(source = Recommendation, target = Barrier, value = Value)

# Create nodes data
ordered_barriers <- c('Uncertainty',
                      'Path dependence',
                      'Compartimentalisation',
                      'Myopic decision-making',
                      'Context dependence',
                      'Undervaluation of multifunctionality',
                      'Limitations in evaluation methods',
                      'Disregard trade-offs',
                      'Lack of public support',
                      'Disregard justice',
                      'Secure funding',
                      'No long-term monitoring',
                      'Lack of supporting regulation',
                      'Economic growth paradigm')
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(data$Recommendation, ordered_barriers)))

links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

nodes$group <- gsub(" ", "-", nodes$name)

color_scale <-
  "d3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(['Participatory-decision-making-process', 'Involve-wide-range-of-experts', 'Legal/regulatory-framework-to-assist-NbS', 'Include-social-justice',
         'Many-future-scenarios', 'Consider-NbS-as-an-option', 'Disincentivise-myopia',
         'Move-beyond-monetary-valuation', 'Multi-scalar-valuation', 'Draw-on-pilots/past-examples',
         'Improve-awareness-of-NbS-co-benefits', 'Multiple-financing-approaches',
         'Early-and-continued-monitoring', 'Behavior/experience-mapping',
         'Uncertainty', 'Path-dependence', 'Compartimentalisation', 'Myopic-decision-making', 'Context-dependence',
         'Undervaluation-of-multifunctionality', 'Limitations-in-evaluation-methods', 'Disregard-trade-offs',
         'Lack-of-public-support', 'Disregard-justice', 'Secure-funding',
         'No-long-term-monitoring', 'Lack-of-supporting-regulation', 'Economic-growth-paradigm'])
     .range(['#3182BDFF', '#6BAED6FF', '#9ECAE1FF', '#C6DBEFFF',
         '#74C476FF', '#A1D99BFF', '#C7E9C0FF',
         '#FD8D3CFF', '#FDAE6BFF', '#FDD0A2FF',
         '#E7BA52FF', '#E7CB94FF',
         '#D6616BFF', '#E7969CFF',
         '#4daf62', '#4daf62', '#4daf62', '#4daf62', '#4daf62',
         '#fb8d3d', '#fb8d3d', '#fb8d3d',
         '#ead156', '#ead156', '#ead156',
         '#e16462', '#e16462', '#e16462',
         ]);
  "

# Create the Sankey diagram
sn <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links, 
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source_id",
  Target = "target_id",
  Value = "value",
  NodeID = "name",
  LinkGroup = "source",
  fontSize = 10,
  NodeGroup = "group",
  colourScale = color_scale,
  margin = list(right = 180, left = 180),
  iterations = 0
)

# Move labels outside of diagram
sn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  sn,
  paste0('
        function(el,x){
        d3.select(el)
        .selectAll(".node text")
        .filter(function(d) { return (["',paste0(links$source,collapse = '","'),'"].indexOf(d.name) > -1);})
        .attr("x", x.options.nodeWidth - 20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");
        d3.select(el)
        .selectAll(".node text")
        .filter(function(d) { return (["',paste0(links$target,collapse = '","'),'"].indexOf(d.name) > -1);})
        .attr("x", x.options.nodeWidth + 5)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start");
        }
        ')
)

# Display the diagram
sn

